# String manipulation in java to get another string

Tags: java, android

I have the String `content://com.android.contact/data/5032` in a variable `Str1`. I want to manipulate `Str1` so that I will get `5032` in another string variable.

Can anyone suggest the answer?

Comment: i am trying split function with "/" but yet to get desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String str1 = "content://com.android.contact/data/5032"
String val = str1.substring(str1.lastIndexOf("//")+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want go get digits from the given string try this:

```
String str = "content://com.android.contact/data/5032";
String str2 = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
System.out.println(str2);
```

Output:

```
5032
```

If you want to split try this:

```
String[] string = str.split("//|/");
System.out.println(string[string.length -1 ]);
```

Output:

```
5032
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str1 = "content://com.android.contact/data/5032";
String str2 = str1.substring(str1.lastIndexOf("/")+1, str1.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

if you only want the last 4 chars, you can do something like this

```
String s = "this is a string";
String ss = s.substring(s.length()-4, s.length());
```

but if you need to extract the number from random positions, you will have to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Please write names of variables starting with a small letter. You can use the `split` method to do this. You might find this related question interesting: [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/string-split-in-java).